Hypothesis testing on densities of a random variable
I'm solving problems, but my answer doesn't match the answer in the textbook.
The problem looks like this:
Given a sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n$. Hypotheses about the type of distribution are represented in the picture (see Graphs of densities f1 and f2).

$H_0$: sample from the distribution f1 (blue graph in the picture),
$H_1$: sample from the distribution f2 (red graph in the picture).


Find $c_1$ and $c_2$. This is an auxiliary step.

I found $ c_1 = 0.5, c_2 = 0.4$.

Find the type $1$ error for the following type of criterion.


$H_0 : X_1 > 2$

$ H_1 : X_1 \leq 2$.



Find the type $2$ error for a criterion of the following kind.


$H_0: X_1 > 2$,
$H_1 : X_1 \leq 2$.

The problem arose with the second and third items of the problem.
My solution:
2.
We're looking for the first type of error. So we accepted hypothesis $H_1: X_1 \leq 2$ (for f2), but hypothesis $H_0: X_1 > 2$ (for f1) was correct.
That is, we are trying to find the probability that X1 lies to the left of $2$ in the f2 distribution. This is the area of a right triangle: $0.5 * 3 * c_2 = 0.6$.
I got the answer $0.6$. The correct answer is $0$.
3.
We are looking for the second type of error. So we accepted hypothesis $H_0$: $X_1 > 2$ (for f1), but hypothesis $H_1: X_1 \leq 2$ (for f2) was correct.
That is, we are trying to find the probability that X1 lies to the right of $2$ in the f1 distribution. This is the area of the triangle with height $c_1$, it is equal to one since it is a density plot.
I got an answer of $1$. The correct answer is $0.27$.
Since I solved both problems incorrectly, I think there is the same error in my solution algorithm. Please help me understand which part of my reasoning is wrong.

The type I error happens when we accept $H_1$ while $H_0$ is true. Given the criterion, we accept $H_1$ when $X_1<=2$. If so, there is no possibility that $X_1$ comes from $H_0$, so the probability is indeed 0. Analogous argument for the type II question.

@nicola, I don't understand yet. So we're trying to find the intersection of the rejected and accepted hypothesis? So in the second case we'll get 0 again?

The hypothesis $H_0$ means that $X_1$ comes from $f_1$; $H_1$ that $X_1$ comes from $f_2$. Now, we can see the value of $X_1$ and decide which theory is correct accordingly. For doing so, we establish a criterion that is reported in your question. Since we are dealing with random variables, our criterion sometimes will be wrong; there might be cases in which we "accept" a theory, but the other is true. A type I error means that we have accepted $H_1$, but actually $H_0$ is the correct theory. [cont]

When we accept $H_1$? When we observe a value of $X_1$ which is less than 2 (that's what our criterion dictates). If so, given the shape of the distribution, we are actually sure that $H_1$ is the correct theory, since $H_0$ cannot produce a value lower than 2.

The type II error happens when we accept $H_0$, but $H_1$ is true. When we accept $H_0$? Our criterion establishes when we observe a $X_1$ value greater than 2. Now, we cannot be so sure that $H_0$ is correct, because also the $f_2$ distribution can produce values greater than 2. The probability in this case is the intersection of the two distributions, divided by 1 (the area of the blue distribution) + the area of the intersection.

Thank you, @nicola! I'm not sure I understand the solution yet, but I'll try to figure it out.
